# Accepting mobile short code texts (e.g. Twitter) with Django

Tags: python, django, mobile-phones, mobile-website, sms-gateway

Ive tried to look up how to accept texts from mobile phones with Django (e.g. like Twitter) to post data to user accounts. All i have ran across is how to make a mobile web app with django as in different layouts etc.. Has anyone any idea where a tutorial on this might be or how in the world to start doing this with django? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a django based SMS application framework called RapidSMS. I am using it for a project at the moment, and it works fine. Here is the link

http://www.rapidsms.org/

Comment: Is is flexible enough to enable you to develop any kind of SMS application?

Comment: Yes it is, you can get SMS from all kinds of phones and supports various gateway protocols. We used it to build a realtime tracking and monitoring product. It also has a parser that relies on regexp, so you can build any structure out of SMS messages

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve what you want:

### **Home-grown solution**

Attach a mobile phone to a PC and periodically read incoming SMS from the phone. Probably the easiest way to accomplish this is with [gammu](http://wammu.eu/gammu/), specifically [gammu-smsd-mysql](http://wammu.eu/docs/man/en/gammu-smsd-mysql.7/). It writes incoming SMS to a MySQL database. Just make sure the phone you use is supported by gammu.

You can easily connect to this database from Django, see [Integrating Django with a legacy database](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/).

I used this approach for a while and it worked reliably, although on a very small scale. If you plan to build a real service that receives thousands of SMS, the home-grown solution is not for you.

### **Professional solution**

Find a service provider that offers an SMS gateway. There are countless providers, the first name that comes to my mind is [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you either need to setup your own gateway with a mobile phone and a software that reads incoming text and processes it or find a service provider. If you buy a short code it may be costly but there should be some services around that allows you to use common number with a keyword to receive and process incoming txts.